# Работа Kivy Android в фоне

Tags: android, python, kivy

Доброе время суток, кто нибудь знает как реализовать подобную задачу на kivy под android?

[Как тут](https://droidqd.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/how-to-make-a-floating-face-bubble-on-home-screen-in-android/)

у меня только задача попроще, надо просто что бы виджет появлялся поверх всех программ и пропадал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это невозможно. Kivy приложение на Android запускается только в режиме fullscreen и ни о каких виджетах, типа "виджет погоды", не может быть и речи.